# Redeclare function in loop

Tags: php, twitter

I'm stumped as to how I would get this working. I'm using the twitteroauth.php library and I am grabbing the users token and token secret from a db query. Here is the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($m))
{   
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
    $consumerKey = "#####";
    $consumerSecret = "#####";
    $oauthToken = $row['oauth_token'];
    $oauthTokenSecret = $row['oauth_token_secret'];
    $userName = $row['username'];

    $query = mysql_query("select url from retweets order by rand() limit 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $retweet = basename($row['url']);

    $method = 'statuses/retweet/'.$retweet.'';
    twitterOAuth($method, $connection->post($method), $connection->http_code, $userName);
}
```

If there are multiple results from mysql, it loops through and says:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare random_from() (previously declared in /usr/share/nginx/www/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php:199) in /usr/share/nginx/www/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php on line 199
```

Since the `$connection` variable relies on `$oauthToken` and `$oauthTokenSecret` from the mysql query, I can't move it outside of the loop, so how would I make it so I can use it in each loop without redeclaring?

Thank you in advance!

Update: This is twitterOAuth

```
function twitterOAuth($method, $response, $http_code, $userName, $parameters = '') {
        if($http_code == 200){
            echo "retweeted successfully @".$userName."<br />";
        }else{
            echo "an error has occurred while retweeting @".$userName."";
            echo "<br />";
            print_r($response);
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix `TwitterOAuth` instead, which is where the redeclaration happens.

Comment: Not familiar with the lib, but maybe declare a single connection object and just change its properties on each iteration?

Comment: how does `twitterOAuth` function look like?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I updated my question with twitterOAuth

Comment: seems to me you should be instantiating the oauth object outside the loop, and seeting the "changeable" parameters only within the loop.

Comment: You're declaring all the variable to pass into the TwitterOAuth, after assigning them, put the TwitterOAuth underneat

Comment: It doesn't look like your problem originates from this `while` loop you posted. Error message states that you are including same file twice, an neither in this loop or `twitteroauth` function you are not including any file.

Comment: @KyleK I did move it below, it says the same thing

Comment: @GabeIsman How would I do that?

Comment: @MarcB How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to look like this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($m))
{   

$consumerKey = "#####";
$consumerSecret = "#####";
$oauthToken = $row['oauth_token'];
$oauthTokenSecret = $row['oauth_token_secret'];
$userName = $row['username'];

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);

$query = mysql_query("select url from retweets order by rand() limit 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$retweet = basename($row['url']);
$method = 'statuses/retweet/'.$retweet.'';

twitterOAuth($method, $connection->post($method), $connection->http_code, $userName);
}
```

You were declaring it before declaring the variables that you wanted to pass into it...

Comment: Same thing with it moved below